# Why i can´t upload images in my mysql database using php

Tags: php, mysql

two weeks ago the application worked well but, the last week i had problems trying to upload images to my data base, i create a name, image and type of mime attribute in the php file and in the database, if anyone have an idea please help

php file

```
'<?php
ini_set('session.save_path',getcwd(). '/tmp');
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
session_start();
$idInmobi=$_SESSION['idInmobiliaria'];
require('conexion.php');
$query="SELECT *  FROM Propiedades";
$resultado=$mysqli->query($query);

 if(isset($_POST['eviar'])){
    $Estado=$_POST['Estado'];
    $Municipio=$_POST['Municipio'];
    $Inmueble=$_POST['TipoInm'];
    $Precio=$_POST['Precio'];
    $Cuartos=$_POST['Cuartos'];
    $Banos=$_POST['Banos'];
    $VentaR=$_POST['VentaRenta'];
    $Descripcion=$_POST['Descripcion'];
    if(!empty($_FILES['Imagen1']) && !empty($_FILES['Imagen2']) && !empty($_FILES['Imagen3']) && !empty($_FILES['Imagen4']) && !empty($_FILES['Imagen5']) && !empty($_FILES['Imagen6']) && !empty($_FILES['Imagen7']) && !empty($_FILES['Imagen8']) && !empty($_FILES['Imagen9'])){
        $nombreImagen=$_FILES['Imagen1']['name'];
        $imagenTemporal=$_FILES['Imagen1']['tmp_name'];
        $type=$_FILES['Imagen1']['type'];

        $nombreImagen2=$_FILES['Imagen2']['name'];
        $imagenTemporal2=$_FILES['Imagen2']['tmp_name'];
        $type2=$_FILES['Imagen2']['type'];

        $nombreImagen3=$_FILES['Imagen3']['name'];
        $imagenTemporal3=$_FILES['Imagen3']['tmp_name'];
        $type3=$_FILES['Imagen3']['type'];

        $nombreImagen4=$_FILES['Imagen4']['name'];
        $imagenTemporal4=$_FILES['Imagen4']['tmp_name'];
        $type4=$_FILES['Imagen4']['type'];

        $nombreImagen5=$_FILES['Imagen5']['name'];
        $imagenTemporal5=$_FILES['Imagen5']['tmp_name'];
        $type5=$_FILES['Imagen5']['type'];

        $nombreImagen6=$_FILES['Imagen6']['name'];
        $imagenTemporal6=$_FILES['Imagen6']['tmp_name'];
        $type6=$_FILES['Imagen6']['type'];

        $nombreImagen7=$_FILES['Imagen7']['name'];
        $imagenTemporal7=$_FILES['Imagen7']['tmp_name'];
        $type7=$_FILES['Imagen7']['type'];

        $nombreImagen8=$_FILES['Imagen8']['name'];
        $imagenTemporal8=$_FILES['Imagen8']['tmp_name'];
        $type8=$_FILES['Imagen8']['type'];

        $nombreImagen9=$_FILES['Imagen9']['name'];
        $imagenTemporal9=$_FILES['Imagen9']['tmp_name'];
        $type9=$_FILES['Imagen9']['type'];


        //se crea archivo temporal binario
        $img_tmp=fopen($imagenTemporal, 'r+b');
        $imagen=fread($img_tmp, filesize($imagenTemporal));
        fclose($img_tmp);

        $img_tmp2=fopen($imagenTemporal2, 'r+b');
        $imagen2=fread($img_tmp2, filesize($imagenTemporal2));
        fclose($img_tmp2);

        $img_tmp3=fopen($imagenTemporal3, 'r+b');
        $imagen3=fread($img_tmp3, filesize($imagenTemporal3));
        fclose($img_tmp3);

        $img_tmp4=fopen($imagenTemporal4, 'r+b');
        $imagen4=fread($img_tmp4, filesize($imagenTemporal4));
        fclose($img_tmp4);

        $img_tmp5=fopen($imagenTemporal5, 'r+b');
        $imagen5=fread($img_tmp5, filesize($imagenTemporal5));
        fclose($img_tmp5);

        $img_tmp6=fopen($imagenTemporal6, 'r+b');
        $imagen6=fread($img_tmp6, filesize($imagenTemporal6));
        fclose($img_tmp6);

        $img_tmp7=fopen($imagenTemporal7, 'r+b');
        $imagen7=fread($img_tmp7, filesize($imagenTemporal7));
        fclose($img_tmp7);

        $img_tmp8=fopen($imagenTemporal8, 'r+b');
        $imagen8=fread($img_tmp8, filesize($imagenTemporal8));
        fclose($img_tmp8);

        $img_tmp9=fopen($imagenTemporal9, 'r+b');
        $imagen9=fread($img_tmp9, filesize($imagenTemporal9));
        fclose($img_tmp9);

        //Envio de carcteres a la base de datos 
        $imagen=mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$imagen);
        $imagen2=mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$imagen2);
        $imagen3=mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$imagen3);
        $imagen4=mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$imagen4);
        $imagen5=mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$imagen5);
        $imagen6=mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$imagen6);
        $imagen7=mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$imagen7);
        $imagen8=mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$imagen8);
        $imagen9=mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$imagen9);
    }else{
        echo'<script languaje="Javascript">alert("Debes de subir al menos una imagen  "); history.back(); </script>';
    }

    $que="INSERT INTO Propiedades (Estado, Municipio, TipoInmueble, Precio, NRecamaras, Nbanos, Tipo, Descripcion, Imagen1, NombreImagen1, TipoImagen1, Imagen2, NombreImagen2, TipoImagen2, Imagen3, NombreImagen3, TipoImagen3, Imagen4, NombreImagen4, TipoImagen4, Imagen5, NombreImagen5, TipoImagen5, Imagen6, NombreImagen6, TipoImagen6, Imagen7, NombreImagen7, TipoImagen7, Imagen8, NombreImagen8, TipoImagen8, Imagen9, NombreImagen9, TipoImagen9, IdentificadorInmobiliaria) VALUES ('$Estado','$Municipio','$Inmueble','$Precio','$Cuartos','$Banos','$VentaR','$Descripcion','$imagen','$nombreImagen','$type','$imagen2','$nombreImagen2','$type2','$imagen3','$nombreImagen3','$type3','$imagen4','$nombreImagen4','$type4','$imagen5','$nombreImagen5','$type5','$imagen6','$nombreImagen6','$type6','$imagen7','$nombreImagen7','$type7','$imagen8','$nombreImagen8','$type8','$imagen9','$nombreImagen9','$type9','$idInmobi')";

    $result=$mysqli->query($que);

    if($result!=false){
        echo  '<script>window.location.assign("inicioAdministradorPropiedades.php");alert("El registro se realizo exitosamente");</script>'; 
    }else{

        echo'<script languaje="Javascript">alert("Lo sentimos algo salio mal, vuelve a intentarlo"); history.back(); </script>';
        }
    }

    ?>'
```

Comment: I am not sure how it worked two weeks ago with using single quote before php tag declaration. Anyway, did you updated your server configuration/versions?

Comment: can please explain that what is the error occurs here?

Comment: Don't save files in a database.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/38829952/267540